# fetch data by id from s3 json file

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, next.js

I have a JSON file stored on s3 that looks like this:

```
[
  {
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Number One"
  },
  {
   "id":"2",
   "name":"Number Two"
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is use the bucket as my API on my NextJS app. So inside /api/posts folder I have the following:

```
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const s3 = new S3();

  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: "bucket_name",
      Key: "key/file_name.json",
    };
    const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const data = response.Body?.toString("utf-8");
    res.status(200).json(data);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
      body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message),
    };
  }
};
```

This works and if I navigate to localhost/api/posts - It shows me the data of the file.

Now, I'm trying to do 2 thing;

1. render all posts -->> this works by using SWR + Fetcher
2. render posts by id

For #2 - I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed considering my api path or s3 object doesn't support query params so how can I write something that lets me do localhost/api/posts/1?

I thoughts about copying the api/posts code into a [id].tsx file under the api/posts path and then doing:

```
const { id } = req.query;
```

and then inside the try:

```
const singlePost = data.find(p => p.id === id)
```

But trying to do that gives **Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)**

So I guess my question is how can I fetch a single post by id as part of the api call within the app?

Comment: As the error mentions `data` is a string (from `response.Body?.toString("utf-8")` I assume), what were you expecting it to be?

Comment: @juliomalves I'm find with whatever it needs to be - however I want to be able to pull "id": 1 only from the api call ?

Comment: fine* --- (spelling)